# Как менять число в коде или брать из описания страницы?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js

Есть код комментария с ВК и чтобы его поставить на несколько страниц сайта надо менять id в конце строки число 123. Как сделать чтобы это число менялось само скажем бралось с описания страницы сайта или названия страницы первые два слова или целое описание не важно ?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    VK.Widgets.Comments("vk_comments", {limit: 10, attach: false}, 123);
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если заголовок страницы - искомый id

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var id = Number(document.title);
    VK.Widgets.Comments("vk_comments", {limit: 10, attach: false}, id);
</script>
```

если же только часть заголовка - id, то надо брать подстроку исходя из шаблона формирования заголовка.

Comment: Так а если мне надо с описания брать страницы: <meta name="description" content="Записать образ iso на болванку(диск dvd, cd) сделать установочный диск. " /> Вот и подставлять в конце того кода в место 123 ?

Comment: Я наверное не правильно написал изначально и запутал с id извиняюсь и буду премного благодарен если ответите :) Мне надо от сюда описание брать : <meta name="description" content="Записать образ iso на болванку(диск dvd, cd) сделать установочный диск. " /> и подставлять или вставлять в место 123 Извините еще раз

Comment: Спасибо огромное все работает на ура :)

Comment: Для meta поменять
`document.title`
на 
`document.head.querySelector("[property~=description][content]").content;`

Comment: Это так получается ? var id = document.head.querySelector("[property~=description][content]").content;

Comment: var id = Number(document.head.querySelector("[property~=description][content]").content);